# What replaces .txt in *nix?

Tags: editors

I know that files in *nix don't have to have extensions as in Windows (`.txt`, etc), so instead `list.txt` a file could just be named `list`.

But if we do embrace the file extensions culture in *nix (as most of use practically do anyway), what would be the most plausible replace for `.txt` specifically?

What simple text file extension wouldn't cause editors to add `CRLF` characters to files as they might add for `.txt`?

Comment: What’s wrong with ```.txt```?  What’s this you say about editors (automatically?) adding CRLF characters to files?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I am just afraid that some editors would behave like ".txt is an hardcore traditional Windows file extension so let's replace all LFs to CRLFs as a token of good friendship between the nations" and this would go unnoticed, for a moment.

Comment: Do you mean text editors *in Windows*? AFAIK text editors in \*nix are not eager to add `CRLF`. Why should we care about editors in Windows. I mean here, on Unix & Linux SE (as opposed to [Super User](https://superuser.com) where Windows is on-topic). My advice: do not use goofy text editors. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski text editors in Linux.

Comment: I've never heard of that. Your question might get a better response if you could give an example of that actually happening.

Comment: OK then. What text editor in Linux does add `CRLF`? Let us replicate the problem.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' if I recall correctly I had a few cases when tabs became spaces or the number of tabulation characters was changed from 4 to two, hence, I also recall a case trailing slashes added. This happened when copying and pasting text between various operating systems and editors so I guess I just developed an anxiety that a similar case would happen with text editors inside Linux.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't know if there is one, there is no problem to solve here, just to prevent in advance, perhaps...

Comment: @sultan  If you cut and paste text between windows, the effect is as if you typed the text yourself (including any invisible control characters like CR). The editor is not taking any specific action either to preserve or modify the text. Vi does have options to convert tabs to spaces as you type them, and to display tabs with non-standard stops, but again it accepts the pasted text as keystrokes, it does not enforce any hidden rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual extension for a text file is `.txt`, so no change there.
  Your second question is more problematical though.  Any text editor will need to mark the end of a line.  DOS and Windows does this with CR/LF (0D 0A) pair for historical reasons¹ whereas *NIX uses a simple LF (0A) character.  So no editor will *normally*² add CRLF to a file under *nix.  Furthermore, as you said in your first sentence, *nix ignores file extensions, so to expect there to be a special extension to achieve this is unrealistic.

Two resources to consider: `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` (see `man dos2unix` for a description of both).  If your text editor won't perform the conversion, then they will handle the conversions for you.

If you need more help you will have to expand the question to explain what you are trying to do.

### Notes

- ¹Doing this enabled files to be copied to a printer without the need for any print processing in the days when DOS was on a floppy that might not even be in the machine.
- ²I'm sure that there is one somewhere in a special mode.  Hence "**normally**"!

Comment: See also the `:set ff=unix` or `:set ff=dos` in the `vim` text editor (`ff` short for `fileformat`). `vim` will detect the format when opening a file.

Comment: For the benefit of those who can’t read Stéphane’s mind — he’s saying that, if an existing file already has CRLF line endings, and you edit it with ``vim``, then `vim` will maintain it in that format, adding new CRLF line endings as needed.